# how to escape single quotes simultaneously with semicolon in bash

Tags: bash, escaping, double-quotes, single-quotes

I can't manage to create a file with such name file;with;separated'name in bash.
I tried to use single and double quotes, slash but it doesn't work. Who could explain me?
F.e. with single quotes  `touch 'file;with;separated'\''name'`
reveals to be `'file;with;separated'\''name'`.

Comment: `touch "file;with;separated'name"`?

Comment: what's your expected file name ?

Comment: i expected to get file with name file;with;separated'name - without any wrapping quotes. but i've understood my mistake

Answer (score 2):

Single quotes can't be nested, you need to backslash them outside quotes or include them in double quotes.

```
touch "file;with;separated'name"
touch file\;with\;separated\'name
touch 'file;with;separated'\'name
touch 'file;with;separated'"'"name
```

etc.

What `ls` shows you isn't the real name of the file, it might add quotes and replace some characters for readability. Use `ls --literal` or `ls -N` to see the name unquoted.

Comment: thanks a lot. i've understood. the solution revealed to be very easy)